# SAMBA 4 Forest Functional Level

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, samba4

What is the highest AD Forest functional level I can use and still have SAMBA 4 function as a domain controller.  Can SAMBA 4 act as a domain controller in a Server 2012 functional level forest? Does functional level matter with SAMBA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Active Directory functional level cannot exceed (to be "supported") 2008 R2. It appears there are still issues with [SAMBA4 + 2012 schema](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8680).

Comment: Is there an update regarding Windows Server 2016 with Samba 4 as a domain controller?